# Django rest framework: Is there a way to clean data before validating it with a serializer?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I've got an API endpoint POST `/data`.
The received data is formatted in a certain way which is different from the way I store it in the db.

I'll use geometry type from postgis as an example.

```py
class MyPostgisModel(models.Model):
    ...
    position = models.PointField(null=True)
    my_charfield = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
    errors = JSONField()  # Used to save the cleaning and validation errors

class MyPostgisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyPostgisModel
        fields = [
            ...
            "position",
            ...
            "my_charfield",
            "errors",
        ]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ...
        # Here the data is coming in the field geometry but in the db, it's called
        # position. Moreover I need to apply the `GEOSGeometry(json.dumps(...))`
        # method as well.
        data["position"] = GEOSGeometry(json.dumps(data["geometry"]))
        return data
```

The problem is that there is not only one field like `position` but many. And I would like (maybe wrongly) to do like the `validate_*field_name*` scheme but for cleaning (`clean_*field_name*`).

There is another problem. In this scheme, I would like to still save the rest of the data in the database even if some fields have raised ValidationError (eg: a CharField that is too long) **but** are not part of *the primary_key/a unique_together constraint*. And save the related errors into a JSONField like this:

```
{
    "cleaning_errors": {
        ...
        "position": 'Invalid format: {
            "type": "NotAValidType",  # Should be "Point"
            "coordinates": [
                4.22,
                50.67
            ]
        }'
        ...
    },
    "validating_errors": {
        ...
        "my_charfield": "data was too long: 'this data is way too long for 10 characters'",
        ...
    }
}
```

For the first problem, I thought of doing something like this:

```py
class BaseSerializerCleanerMixin:
    """Abstract Mixin that clean fields."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize the cleaner strategy."""
        # This is the error_dict to be filled by the `clean_*field_name*`
        self.cleaning_error_dict = {}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_fields(self, data):
        """Clean the fields listed in self.fields_to_clean before validating them."""
        cleaned_data = {}
        for field_name in getattr(self.Meta, "fields", []):
            cleaned_field = (
                getattr(self, "clean_" + field_name)(data)
                if hasattr(self, "clean_" + field_name)
                else data.get(field_name)
            )
            if cleaned_field is not None:
                cleaned_data[field_name] = cleaned_field
        return cleaned_data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """Reformat data to put it in the database."""
        cleaned_data = self.clean_fields(data)
        return super().to_internal_value(cleaned_data)
```

I'm not sure that's a good idea and maybe there is an easy way to deal with such things.

For the second problem ; catching the errors of the validation without specifying with `is_valid()` returning `True` when no primary_key being wrongly formatted, I'm not sure how to proceed.